# Pinout of the 24 pin connector of the P5V0A?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, parallel-port, mipi

Where can I get the pinout for the P5V04A SUNNY camera 24 pin flex connector used in the raspberry camera module v1.3??
(the pinout of the tiny yellow part on the camera)
I need to know the function for all the 24 pins.
Not just the CSI interface pin information
Hope someone can help me please.
[image]